# How can I replace images locally on smartphone

Tags: html, mobile, smartphone, mobile-development, mobile-devices

How can I locally replace, for example, an image displayed by a certain application on a smartphone?

Comment: How show images? background or with `<img>`

Comment: For example you can use `https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture` to handle images source for every dimensions!

Comment: There is no general way to do this. It would depend a number of factors including where the image was coming from and what OS the phone was running.

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to do on Android?